# Смещение элемента массива плавно вниз Консоль

Tags: c#

Подскажите как сделать, что бы масив начиная с последнего элемента, плавно опускался вниз и исчезал?
Принцип тетриса, но реализовать не получаеться.

```
string[] icon = new string[]
    {
        "       ****                                                              ",
        "     **    **                                                            ",
        "    **      **                                                           ",
        "    **      **                         ****                      ****    ",
        "     **    **                        **    **                  **    **  ",
        "      **  **        ****            **      **                **      ** ",
        "        **        **    **          **      **                **     **  ",
        "         ㋡      **      **          **    **                   **  **   ",
        "       ./♥\\.    **      **           **  **                      **     ",
        "       .||.       **    **              **                        ㋡     ",
        "                   **  **               ㋡                       ./█\\.  ",
        "                     **                ./♥\\.                    .||.    ",
        "                     ㋡                 .||.                             ",
        "                    ./█\\.                                               ",
        "                    .||.                                                 "
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] icon =
            {
                "       ****                                                              ",
                "     **    **                                                            ",
                "    **      **                                                           ",
                "    **      **                         ****                      ****    ",
                "     **    **                        **    **                  **    **  ",
                "      **  **        ****            **      **                **      ** ",
                "        **        **    **          **      **                **     **  ",
                "         ㋡      **      **          **    **                   **  **   ",
                "       ./♥\\.    **      **           **  **                      **     ",
                "       .||.       **    **              **                        ㋡     ",
                "                   **  **               ㋡                       ./█\\.  ",
                "                     **                ./♥\\.                    .||.    ",
                "                     ㋡                 .||.                             ",
                "                    ./█\\.                                               ",
                "                    .||.                                                 "
            };

            string emptyString = "\n";

            // Тут двигаем наш массив вниз.
            for(int i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                // Тут выводим пустые строки в перед картинкой.
                for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write(emptyString);
                }
                // Тут выводим наш массив.
                for(int j=0; j < icon.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(icon[j]);
                }

                // Ждем 1 секунду.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо. А подскажите можно как то сделать что бы они начинали появляться с крайнего элемента массива и потихоньку вниз пока не исчезнут, или так не получиться и обязательно все должны появиться?

Comment: @АртемМазуров строка - это массив,по ней можно выводить через индекс,просто нужен еще 1 цикл